# No getter method for property

Tags: java, jsp, object, struts

Hi I am trying to use struts to get a bean to my jsp code the bean I am using in my jsp page is:  but whenever I run the jsp I am receiving

> No getter method for property: "testData.team.type" of bean: "unitForm".

I am trying to write baseball to my JSP page.

The code for my action form is:

```
import com.TestGettingData;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
public class UnitForm extends ActionForm {

private TestGettingData testData = new TestGettingData();  

public TestGettingData getTestData() {
    return testData;
}

public void setTestData(TestGettingData testData) {
    this.testData = testData;
} 

}
```

testing data class has:

```
public class TestGettingData extends Sport{

    private String team = "Yankees"; 

private String position = "short stop";  

public void setTeam(String tm) {    
    team = tm; } 

public String getTeam() {     
        return team; } 

public void setPosition(String po) {    
    position = po; } 

public String getPosition() {   
    return position; 
    } 
}
```

and finally in my sport class:

```
public class Sport{

    public String type = "baseball";

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


}
```

Comment: Can you also add what you are doing in your JSP?

Comment: in jsp I have:  <tr>
 <td>
 This is a data test:
 

 
 ${unitForm.testData.type}
 
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `testData.team.type`, try `testData.type`. `type` is a property in `testData` not in `team`.

**Update**

`${unitForm.testData.type}` should display "baseball" in your JSP.

Comment: I tried that and I get No getter method for property: testData.type of bean: "unitForm"

Comment: @billy: Can you update your post to include what you are doing in your JSP?

Comment: @billy: Updated the answer. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Hi I tried ${unitForm.testData.type} and I got: The class com.utils.TestGettingData' does not have a readable property 'type'.

Comment: @billy: Your import statement (`import com.TestGettingData;`) in `UnitForm` suggests different package.